# C# TabPage.Controls.Add too long

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

At run time, I add one control to a tabpage and I notice that it takes 0.5 sec to do it. It's rather long and I would like to reduce this time. I tried Suspend/ResumeLayout but for only one action it's no relevant and do not improved anythng. Any ideas?

Comment: My best guess is that what is taking the time is something you do in the constructor of your tabPage.

Comment: @klaus: He is adding _to_ a TabPage.

Comment: What kind of Control? If it's a Grid with a lot of data then it figures. Adding a Button shouldn't even take 0.005 sec.

Comment: @Henk, it's a custom user control rather big

Comment: @Toto: then first compare with the time to add something simple, then focus on that control. It's probably nothing to with TabControl

Comment: Are you sure the time is taken while the control is being added, not while the control is being instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Information provided is not sufficent.

I think either your system(computer) is of low configuration or you are adding a control like datagrid, listview with lots of data in it.
you can test perfomence by adding some simple controls like listbox, textbox and compare.
are you adding control in pageload or using thread.